# Why int datatype has a bigger size than float in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I am using Python 3.7.1 and I was confused when I checked the size of int in compare with float

```
from os import getsizeof
a = 5
b = 5.0

print(getsizeof(a))
>> 28
print(getsizeof(b))
>> 24
```

So int has a bigger size than float. Why python has such a strange size for these types?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In python when a value is initialized to a variable it becomes an object to the value. There is no bound in the size of the object. The size of the object i.e, the size of the variable can be extents upto the size of the RAM in your computer this means the size is not bounded to the restricted to the default value. It can be either int or float. For example,

```
>>>a=0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
>>> type(a)
<class 'int'>
>>>sys.getsizeof(a)
40
```

Answer (score 0):

The Python 'int' is not a simple 32 or 64 Bit value, but a class that can hold arbitrarily large numbers. That's why it is much larger than 4 or 8.

Same argument is valid for float.

Why the size is different, is an implementation detail (and can change e.g. when the number gets bigger).